# Build Java RMI applications with Eclipse (How to do rmic)

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I'm trying to develop a Java RMI application and found out that it's not straight forward to tell eclipse to compile it using rmic.

Are there any available addons (if so which one do you recommend)?

or

what are the ways to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Java 5 there is no need to use the `rmic` tool since stubs are now dynamically generated. I'd suggest following an updated tutorial which is more geared towards RMI implementations for Java 5 or greater. Following the [RMI Guide for Java 5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/) should give you a decent start.

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately I'm working with a legacy system where I have to work with Java 1.4

Answer (score 2):

You have plugins for eclipse for RMI applications like this one: http://www.genady.net/rmi/index.html

Edit:
Also, some free plugins like this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rmi-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try the free one.